# Passing Value from PHP output to JS

Tags: javascript, php, bash

I have two php files, a fecthdrive.php and index.php

I currently have a bash script

```
#!/bin/sh php fetchdrive php start http://localhost/
```

This starts my local index.php file, and puts the output of fetchdrive.php into console log as the array, which works,
here's the code that outputs the log from fetchdrive.php

```
$feedDrive = &fetching();
printf("%s", json_encode($feedDrive)); ?>
```

The output that displays in console is

```
["UUENmU0","UbU9ucn"]
```

Which is correct. All I want to do now, is to pass these two values to the index.php file.
Now, before asking why I don't just execute the php file in js, it's because I have to run the php file via CLI. So, how do I go about passing these two values to html/js in my index.php file?

Comment: I would write them to a file and then include that file into your index.php file

Comment: How would I go about this? The command I need to output the log is "php fetchdrive"

Comment: Try adding **> outfile** after the CLI command - that should redirect stdout from the console to a file named **outfile**

Comment: It's just creatinga  blank outfile.txt file

Comment: I fixed it by outputting the file using php instead.